# Adding/removing icon in downloadButton() and fileInput()

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

In Shiny, we have `downloadButton()` and `fileInput()` buttons for downloading and uploading data respectively.

However it happens that, with `downloadButton()` there is *download* icon, and however with `fileInput()` no icon is attached.

In my Shiny app, I have both buttons. However since one of them has icon attached, it brings some kind of visual inconsistency in my App.

So, I either want to remove such icon from `downloadButton()`, or add some *upload* button with `fileInput()` to bring consistency.

However, it appears that there is not any direct approach to perform either of them.

So can anybody suggest here if there is any way to :

Either remove icon from `downloadButton()` Or, attach some *upload*
    icon with `fileInput()`

Any pointer is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add an icon to fileInput(), add a list to the buttonLabel. e.g.

```
shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    fileInput("myFileInput",label="Test",buttonLabel=list(icon("folder"),"TestyMcTestFace"))
  ),
  function(input, output, session){
  }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the source code of `downloadButton`, you will see that changing/removing the button is pretty straightforward

```
downloadButton
## function (outputId, label = "Download", class = NULL, ...) 
## {
##     aTag <- tags$a(id = outputId, class = paste("btn btn-default shiny-download-link", 
##         class), href = "", target = "_blank", download = NA, 
##         icon("download"), label, ...)
## }
## <environment: namespace:shiny>
```

You just need to replace `icon("download")` with `NULL`. Here is a complete example

```
myDownloadButton <- function(outputId, label = "Download"){
  tags$a(id = outputId, class = "btn btn-default shiny-download-link", href = "", 
         target = "_blank", download = NA, NULL, label)
}

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(myDownloadButton("download")),
  function(input, output, session){
    output$download = downloadHandler(
      "file.rds", function(file){ saveRDS(mtcars, file) }
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor. Is there any way to add icon to fileInput()?

Comment: I actually tried to come up with a similar idea for `fileInput`s but didn't find a way to add an icon there.