# Adding an icon to selectInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Hello I am working on Shiny Dashboard. The following article helped me to add an icon to the `fileInput` in shiny.

[Adding/removing icon in downloadButton() and fileInput()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350509/adding-removing-icon-in-downloadbutton-and-fileinput)

I was hoping if there is a way to add icons to selectInput as well in shiny. I want to maintain a consistency of icons in my sidebar menu.

I tried using the below code however it does not serve the purpose

```
sidebarItem(selectInput("vars", "Select a variable:",choices=c("Users", 
"New_Users"), multiple=F), icon = icon("paw"), tabName = "")
```

I am really hoping if there is a solution to this.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same approach, set the label a as list with an icon and a string.

```R
sidebarItem(selectInput("vars", list(icon("paw"),"Select a variable:"),choices=c("Users", 
    "New_Users"), multiple=F))
```

Comment: Hello Geovany, Thanks a lot for this. It worked like magic!!. I tried to increase the size of the text and the icon, however I am unable to do this. Is there a way to adjust that as well that you can suggest please.

Comment: Hello Geovany, Also if I can edit the color of the text and icon as well

Comment: I'm glad it works. Please open a new question and indicate if you want to change the font size/color for all the select inputs in your app or just one specific widget.